# How override default value of socket timeout or connect timeout in apache camel?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

While using apache camel version 2.12.4 with java, I am facing a socketTimeoutException: read time out when once of the restful web service when I dont receive respons within **30 seconds**. I want to change the default sockeTimeout and connectTimeout values in RestletEndpoint class which is a part of camel jar.

I am using restlet in my camel router as below

```
routeDefinition = from(
                "restlet:/AccountInfo/getAccountDetails?socketTimeout=900000&connectTimeout=900000&threadMaxIdleTimeMs=900000&restletMethods=POST&restletBinding=#queryStringToHeadersRestletBinding")
                .process(getAccountDetailsFromProcessor);
```

I tried setting **socketTimeout** and **connectTimeout** values in the parameters as above.

I have found below is a class in camel jar but do not know how to override these default values.

```
public class RestletEndpoint extends DefaultEndpoint implements HeaderFilterStrategyAware {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 80;
    private static final String DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = "http";
    private static final String DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30000;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30000;
```

Comment: Those timeouts are used when you use to("restlet") and not from("restlet")